# After upgrade to 4.7 on Drupal 7, Can't edit a contact

Tags: contacts, error

I get the following error and backtrace. If I disable the Formal title option in Admin Display Settings then I dont' get the error.

Exception: "Unsupported html-element "

```
#0 /home/saintfran/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Individual.php(81): CRM_Core_Form->addField("formal_title", (Array:0))
#1 /home/saintfran/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.php(766): CRM_Contact_Form_Edit_Individual::buildQuickForm(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact))
#2 /home/saintfran/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(540): CRM_Contact_Form_Contact->buildQuickForm()
#3 /home/saintfran/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#4 /home/saintfran/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact), "display")
#5 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact), "display")
#6 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#7 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#8 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", "New Contact", (Array:1))
#9 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#10 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#11 /home/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#12 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "add")
#13 /home/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#14 /home/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#15 {main}
```

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17831

Comment: replicated on [dmaster](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/), seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar issue is being filed here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17831.

This has been fixed in 4.7.2 at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7770/files.

Update: As xml files are not included in the downloaded Civi. For the time being, can you please make the following changes at `fields()` function in `CRM/Contact/DAO/Contact.php`.

```
'formal_title' => array(
   'name' => 'formal_title',
   .
   .
   .
   'export' => true,
   'html' => array(        <--- include this
     'type' => 'Text',
   ) ,
 ) ,
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the change to the xml file. I tried downloading the master and upgrading but get a white screen of death. then i tried just updating the  CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Individual.php file but still get the same error. No clue where to update the  xml/schema/Contact/Contact.xml file.

Comment: @frTommy My bad, I missed to mention xml are not included in the downloaded civi. Updated the answer to work for now.

Comment: After making the edit to the file, I realized it should be 'Text' instead of 'Select'. The Formal Title field is just a regular text field instead of a select field. But after changing it to 'Text' that fixed the issue.

Comment: yeah, thats correct, was a typo ;)